# vuejs: call function from parent from child dataAttr

Tags: vue.js

I have a wrapper component (waypoint) which collects child elements. On the child elements I want to set functions which should be executed from the wrapper component, how can I do that?

//page

```
//template
<v-waypoint>
  <div 
    :data-wp-cb="animateIn"
    // :data-wp-cb="animateIn.bind(this)"  
    class="js-wp"

//methods
animateIn() {
  // do something
}
```

//waypoint component

```
update(el) {
  const cb = el.dataset.wpCb
  cb() // cb is not a function
}
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: It is a little unclear where and which method you want to call: 1) from the parent component - call the method defined in the child component? or 2) from the child component - call the method defined in the parent component? Show sample code...

Comment: The method "animateIn" or any else is definded in the page.vue file and should be called from the waypoint component. the waypoint gets the functionname via the dataAttr from the collected element.

Comment: Try this let fun = 'animateIn'; this.$parent[fun]();

Comment: @PatelPratik $parent does the trick ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should solve it emitting the event from child to the parent.

Waypoint component:

```
update(param) {
  this.$emit('update-from-child', param);
}
```

Page component:

```
<v-waypoint @update-from-child="localMethod">
  <div 
    :data-wp-cb="animateIn"
    // :data-wp-cb="animateIn.bind(this)"  
    class="js-wp"
```

This is how vue deals with child -> parent comunication. For more info, check the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html).

Comment: hmm but than I can only set one function, what if every element should call another function?

Comment: Then you create another `this.$emit('another-emit-from-child)` in the child and catch with another `@another-emit-from-child="anotherLocalMethod` in parent.

Comment: Maybe this is the vue-way, but I think it's more readable if the function is defined on the element and the waypoint wrapper is always directly related with the elements inside. So parent will never loose it's connection. Or has the use of $parent, in this case, a negative impact?

Comment: According to vue's docs, `In most cases, reaching into the parent makes your application more difficult to debug and understand, especially if you mutate data in the parent. When looking at that component later, it will be very difficult to figure out where that mutation came from.`, see https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html